# HSQLDB database manager on a remote site or vps

Tags: java, database, hsqldb, vps

i have a vps which is running a HSQLDB, the problem is that i dont know how to connect to the database remotely and when i logon to my vps via ssh, the HSQLDB database manager applet will not run as it requires x11.

can anyone help please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SqlTool which is a separate jar bundled with HSQLDB.

This is a command line database access tool. See the Guide.

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/index.html

HSQLDB must run as a server to allow connections from other processes.

Comment: i have tried sqltool as well.. but i was never able to get it to connect

Comment: Added requirement for connection